# HTTP errors as json in nginx

Tags: python, nginx, error-handling, uwsgi

I have Python Flask application that uses `@app.errorhandler` to return json a object instead of the typical HTML messages when occurrs a bad request, method not allowed, page not found or any other HTTP exception.

I am now trying to make nginx handle such things with only partial success. When I make a request using an invalid method (e.g. PATCH) I get the json message. But when I use an unexisting page, I get the typical HTML message.

This is how my nginx server configuration looks like. It is the example given in the Flask [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/deploying/uwsgi/) with two extra lines at the end:

```
server {
    location / {
        limit_except GET POST {
            deny all;
        }

        try_files $uri @yourapplication;
    }
    location @yourapplication {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
    }

    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    include api_json_errors.conf;
}
```

where `api_json_errors.conf` is something like this:

```
error_page 400 = @400;
location @400 { return 400 '{"status":400,"message":"Bad request"}\n'; }
```

Comment: Unexisting page is 404 error status code. Do you have an appropriate `error_page` in `api_json_errors.conf` for it? btw, why do you even use `proxy_intercept_errors`? Shouldn't be it just enough to return response from flask application since it's already in json?

Comment: @Grin Yes, I am basically using this https://github.com/jay-nginx/api_workshop/blob/master/errors_json.conf with minor modifications and not removing any error code.

Comment: may be you should try [uwsgi_intercept_errors](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.html#uwsgi_intercept_errors) instead of `proxy_intercept_errors` since the latter is used with `proxy_pass`

Comment: @Grin That did the trick!

Comment: Glad to help! But I still think you should not use this and let Flask to do its job by returning errors in appropriate format :)

Comment: @Grin The logic behind this choice is to remove from flask as much traffic as I can, allowing nginx to catch errors first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [uwsgi_intercept_errors](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.html#uwsgi_intercept_errors) with `uwsgi_pass`

And `proxy_intercept_errors` with `proxy_pass`